# Im trying to modify a FNF mod to randomize the jumpscare that appears, but, simply: nothing appears?

Tags: javascript, random, switch-statement

```
function eventFunction(params) {
    var length:Float = Std.parseFloat(params[1]);
    var portrait:String = 'Gold';
    switch (PlayState.dadOpponent.curCharacter.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'gold-headless':
        var i = math.round(math.random(1, 3))
            switch (i) {
                case (i == 1):
                portrait = 'GoldAlt';
                break;
                case (i == 2):
                portrait = 'GoldAlt2';
                break;
                case (i == 3):
                portrait = 'GoldAlt3';
                break;
            }
    }
```

heres the code. i have 3 images set up and when i remove the switch thing an image does show up, but when i want 3 random different images for the game to pick from then nothing shows up. sry if this is stupid but im really bad at javascript

Comment: why do you write `case (i == 1)`? thats not how you make a `switch case`. This is not an `if/else` statement. Your syntax should look like this `case 1:  portrait = 'GoldAlt'; break;` and so forth for the other values

Comment: The colon in the variable is your first flag is you debug it (unless you are using TypeScript?)  `Std` looks like Java...TypeScript? `var length:Float = Std.parseFloat(params[1]);`

Comment: zer00ne its some custom things with the engine the mod uses, ignore that

Comment: can't do much if you don't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem

Comment: youd need the whole gosh darn game cause it uses forever engine

Comment: @zer00ne thats crap with the engine, im really just focusing on the switch itself and why it pops up nothing

Answer (score 0):

**My answer only applies if your language is JavaScript and not Java**

---

1. You have syntax error - JS is case sensitive. So there is no `math`, only `Math`
2. [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) does not accept any arguments (opposite of e.g. PHP [`rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)
3. `switch ValueToMath`, so your `(i == 2)` should be matched against `switch (true)`. Should be `case [1/2/3]:`

So final version of your code:

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

let i = rand(1, 3);
let portrait = null;

console.log(i);
switch (i) {
  case 1:
    portrait = 'GoldAlt';
    break;
  case 2:
    portrait = 'GoldAlt2';
    break;
  case 3:
    portrait = 'GoldAlt3';
    break;
}

console.log(portrait);
```

Comment: Still really nothing pops up :pain:

Comment: @hi14443 Well, you do nothing with your `portrait`, just assign value. Also ensure that outer `switch` (that can be replaced with `if`) is reached.